# Sketch current flow of circuit

Tags: current

I have the following circuit

[image]

R1 = 5kΩ, R2 = 10kΩ, L = 1H and Vs = 10V. When t<0 the circuit is in steady-state, and when t=0 the with goes from closed to open.

I don't know how to solve the following:

- Sketch the current flow in interval t=[-0.1, 1]

Hope that someone can help/guide me!

Comment: What have you tied? What are the steady state conditions? How does an inductor behave to DC?

Answer (score 1):

We know from basic electronics that current cannot change instantaneously in an inductor, and that inductors store electrical energy .

Hence for t>0 , the inductor will keep the current flowing in the same direction through R1 and R2.

Off course the magnitude will slowly decay until it reaches zero.

This depends on the value of inductance (stored energy) and Resistance (dissipating energy)
Notice that the inductor voltage switch due to current flow.

[image: Current flow after switch open]

Comment: Ah, so with respect to the interval [-0,1, 1] ms, i know when its <0 (in this case with -0.1) the inductor is charging, and as the t>0 the inductor will start to discharge, as the switch opens, and that is what i have to sketch?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework question here are some pointers.

In order to 'sketch' a graph of current against time you need to do a few (simple) calculations first.

(1) Steady state (t > 0) - means the current through the inductor is at its maximum value. What component(s) control this final current value and how could you calculate this value. This will give you the initial current value (Io).

(2) After the switch is open (t >= 0) this initial current value (Io) will start to decay **exponentially**.

(a) What is the time constant of this decay circuit? (*remember the switch is open so that part of the circuit is disconnected*)

(b) What will the current be after 1 second if Io is the initial current.

With the values from (1a) and (2b) and knowing it's a **decaying exponential** you should be able to sketch the graph of current against time.

Comment: Try follow me through here: First of i calculate the current form the voltage source to t<0. First i find Rtotal in parallel 5kΩ*10kΩ/(5kΩ+10kΩ) = 3,3kΩ. Voltage is 10V, so the current is 10V*3,3kΩ = 0,003 A. Then i calculate I_o = 10V/5kΩ = 0,002 A.
When the circuit decay it's t>0, and i don't know how to calculate the current after 1 second - is the 0,002 A what runs through per second? 
Thanks for the help in advice!

Comment: @EmilSkovgaard  No.  Initially you only need be concerned with the current through the coil i.e the current through R1. In steady state the voltage across the coil can be taken as 0V. When the switch is opened the two resistors,  R1 and R2, will appear as a **series  load** to the coil (draw the circuit and you'll see why).  To calculate the time constant  t = L/R. (L in Henries and R in Ohms). To calculate the current at T seconds  I(1)= initial current (Io) * exp (- T / time constant)). Its a very important concept, well worth the effort learning it.